# Upgrading to a first class

Tags: tickets, upgrades

I was given a two economy tickets for a trip. Is it possible to exchange the two economy tickets for one first class ticket?

Comment: Perhaps, but it depends on the trip. Is it by plane/train/bus/... from where to where, ...?

Comment: **Yes, of course.**  You can apply the fares, minus any penalties, to a new ticket in any class of service, either paying the difference or using the balance on future travel.  You will have to call the airline to do this.

Comment: Hard to say. Is it possible to exchange 2 bicycles for 1 car? In theory yes, but don't expect it would be a standard service.

Answer (score 3):

In general no. You might be able to cancel both and use these monies to buy a first class ticket. Or you might not, depending on the tickets you bought. Read the email it came with. It is a tried and true tactic (I did it for example) to [buy two tickets for yourself](https://servicehub.amadeus.com/view-solution?p_p_id=101&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=2&_101_struts_action=%2Fasset_publisher%2Fview_content&_101_assetEntryId=938448&_101_type=content&_101_groupId=20195&_101_urlTitle=how-to-book-an-extra-seat-for-cabin-baggage-cbbg-or-for-personal-comfort-exst-&inheritRedirect=true) (or perhaps yourself and your musical instrument) because it's comfortable enough and yet still way cheaper than business (at least on transoceanic flights this is typically the case) so you can't expect the airline to give you a (much) more expensive ticket in place of two cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.

In general 2 economy class tickets will not cover a single first class ticket.

You might try a business class ticket instead.